# Configuring Dynamic routed datasource by JdbcTemplate and properties file

Tags: spring, datasource, jdbctemplate

Is it possible to configure `dynamic route datasource` by `application.properties` and `JdbcTemplate` ?   I can use this stuff to configure simple datasource.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/ this one

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple datasources only by configuration in application.properties.

You have to define multiple Datasources as bean like described here

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

and than define new bean of type AbstractRoutingDataSource.